# What are all the ways to generate resources without scavenging?

Tags: state-of-decay

What are all the ways that exist in the game to generate resources other than scavenging? e.g. the upgraded watchtower has an action to trade influence for a few ammo resources. You can generate food resources by building a garden/greenhouse. I believe you can generate fuel from food if you research the right thing at the library.

Are there any ways to generate construction materials or medicine resources?

I know you can build outposts on those resources, which seems to lower your daily usage, but that doesn't last indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

If you're playing the storyline mode then no, you can't create [Medicine](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Medicine) or [Construction Material](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Construction_Materials) without outposts or trading. In the DLCs, there are other options ("Leave the valley" when resources run out in Breakdown, and request resource drops in Lifeline) but in vanilla game your choices are much more limited.

Answer (score 0):

I have found no way to create construction materials, which are easily the most important resource.

You can create medicine by setting up a medicine outpost and having construction materials available. Each day, your outpost will consume one construction material and produce three medicine.

You should also be able to acquire these materials through trading with other survivors, but this isn't something you can initiate yourself.